# How to make a custom field required in Jira?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api, jira-agile

I have a Jira custom field and I would like to make it required for a specific project. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to "Field Configurations" and click on the following:
[image]

Click on the given issue type that you're interested in [image]

Go to the given field and make it required
[image]